# Почему "грейпфрут" пишется без буквы К, если "фруКт" с ней?

Tags: орфография, этимология

Да и говорить с буквой К проще и привычней.

Answer (score 2):

Название образовано от англ. grape (виноград) и fruit (фрукт). Получается, написание исключительно по звучанию?

Comment: Не совсем по звучанию. В языке-источнике оно и пишется без К. Причем отнюдь не только в английском, в большинстве индоевропейских, начиная с греческого. Поэтому, хотя достоверно и нельзя сказать, откуда слово пришло, но тем не менее можно утверждать, что "к" во "фрукте" есть только в латыни и русском (ну и близкороственных славянских).

Answer (score 0):

> Да и говорить с буквой К проще и привычней

Потому что это заимствование из английского. А там говорится "фрут".

Аналогично сейчас некоторые копируют английское произношение в слове *"club"*. "Клаб", хотя обычно в России говорили "клуб". "Клаббер" -- завсегдатай ночных клубов.

Answer (score 0):

Есть переведенные слова, а есть заимствованные.

В 1814 году на Ямайке торговцы переименовали плод в грейпфрут.
Название образовано от англ. grape (виноград) и fruit (фрукт), так как плоды грейпфрута часто собираются в грозди, напоминая тем самым грозди винограда.
[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BF%D1%84%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82)

"Виноградный фрукт" не укладывается в русском языке. Поэтому его полностью заимствовали.

При этом "говорить с буквой К проще и привычней" далеко не всем, особенно неудобно тем, кто изучал английский, или поколению Next - 90-х и младше.